# Help with using different ERC-20 tokens with my smart contract.Solidity

Tags: solidity

Hello im making some smart contracts and i would like the user to pay in stablecoin for example usdc.

```
uint price=500;

function sendUSDC() public payable {
 address.send(price in USDC)
}
```

I would like when calling this func to send USDC and i dont know how to do it.Could someone please help or at least send a tutorial or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include token interface in your contract, you can add below code or you can just import openzeppelin's ERC20 contract interface.

```
interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}
```

and do following function in your contract:

`IERC20(erc20TokenContractAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, toAddress, amount);`

Before doing that, you need to get approval from wallet owner by using a different agent, say JavaScript/client.

`IERC20(erc20TokenContractAddress).approve(spenderAccount, amount)`

Explained in detail here: https://medium.com/@harsha_90164/accept-dai-usdc-or-any-erc20-token-to-a-smart-contract-89b836228144